# Referencing the subtype within a trait in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, covariance, scala-2.10, contravariance

With the vast support for generics in Scala, what is the best way to achieve the following cyclic parameter bounds, where `C` in `Command[A, C]` is a subtype of itself (i.e. `UserCommand` or `SystemCommand`)?

Note: I have omitted the lower/upper type bounds for `C` - as the question implies, I am unsure how to express this in a way that compiles, or if I'm missing a feature in Scala specifically intended to solve this type of cyclic problem.

```
trait CommandPrerequisite[-A, +C] {
   val command: C
   def isValid(aggregate: A): Boolean
}

trait Command[A, C] {
   def prerequisites: List[CommandPrerequisite[A, C]]
}

trait SystemCommand extends Command[System, SystemCommand] {
   // System specific definitions.
}

trait UserCommand extends Command[User, UserCommand] {
   // User specific definitions.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want *f-bounded polymorphism*. All you need to change is the signature of `trait Command`:

```
trait Command[A, C <: Command[A, C]] {
```